# Abstract method error runtime crash

Tags: java, android, abstract-methods

I'm developer and game developers use my library in their apps only a single developer reported a runtime Abstract method error crash issue on Android device and when i looked into the proguard mapping on where its happenig it's pointing to Line 68 in this class [org.bson.util.AbstractCopyOnWriteMap](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/util/AbstractCopyOnWriteMap.java).

**Crash Report:**

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
abstract method "java.util.Map com.mypackage.sdk.impl.bf.a(java.util.Map)"
com.mypackage.sdk.impl.bf. (SourceFile:68)`

**Proguard Mapping :**

`org.bson.util.AbstractCopyOnWriteMap -> com.mypackage.sdk.impl.bf:
    java.util.Map delegate -> a`

The weird part is, it doesn't happen everytime it randomly happens and i noticed it only on Android 4.4.2 platform and only that developer reported it. Does anybody have an idea on why its crashing ?

It's different from the normal Abstract Method error crash, mostly its a compile time issue, but it can happen @ runtime if the jars not getting packaged properly, but thats not seems to be the issue here. It will be helpful if someone can provide an insight on how to debug this one.

Comment: @alfasin line 68 is constructor

Comment: I'm just using the org.bso.util open source package classes in my library and i'm able to compile and run the app.